# organizing java code when using try catch finally blocks

Tags: java, coding-style, try-catch

i am a java newbie. i have a question regarding how to organize java code when using try catch finally blocks. suppose i have to read some text files and do some computations on the stored file contents. how should my code look like?

For example

code 1 looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

try{

//open files using BufferedReader, read and store the file contents.

}catch(IOException e){

e.printStackTrace();

}
finally{

//close the files

}
// do computations on the data
}
```

code 2 looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

try{

//open files using BufferedReader, read and store the file contents.

// do computations on the data

}catch(IOException e){

e.printStackTrace();

}
finally{

//close the files

}
}
```

which of the two is a better coding practice? Also should finally block be placed just after
try catch or it can be placed towards the end.

Comment: method 2 because you probably need the data if you want to do computations on it.

Comment: Calling `e.printStackTrace()` in a `catch` block is *not* handling the exception. This is the classic [try/catch/ignore anti-pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EmptyCatchClause).

Comment: I would only put what needs to be in a try catch inside the try catch.  Reading the file will throw an exception, so Id put that in the try catch. If your computations do, then put those in a separate try catch, if not, move them outside. So im kind of recommending code 1

Comment: Yes use method 1 but actually handle the error in the catch block.

Comment: If you use method 1 you have to make sure you handle any other errors which may be thrown if the files were not opened when doing your computations.

Comment: @Asaph I literally lost a job over a "should never happen, print to console" that should have been a "should never happen, crash."

Comment: @djechlin Sorry to hear that. Sounds a bit harsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java 7 and try-with-resources.

```
try(Connection = pool.getConnection()) { // or any resource you open, like files
// ...

} // auto closes
```

This feature comes close to deprecating `finally` - I have personally not found a use case for `finally` once this feature was added and suggest you avoid it.  It's like `goto` or arguably `continue`, or even `for` loops as far as functional programming is concerned - newer features have made the use unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Finally block should be placed just after try-catch. Where you want to do the computations on your data is up to you... but if you put it after the try-catch block, it will attempt the computations even if an exception is thrown, unless you use a condition.

Answer (score 0):

The second method should be used because it is going to be easier to make computations on the data without running into variable scope issues. However, both ways can work depending on the computations that need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

The second.

The idea with exceptions is you throw them at the point where a problem is detected and they are catched not earlier then the first point where the earlier problem does no longer affects the execution of the code. Possibly by doing some handling in the catch block and some cleanup using a finally block.

In your first code sample the code following the catch is still affected by the error that caused the exception. So you caught it to early. Which means you may have to add an if statement around it which unnecessarily raises the complexity of the function.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your system specifics, I see two possible cases:

1)**File is large**. Then you cant load it into the memmory. And you should read pices of file one by one and do your logic on every pice. This will prevent you from running out of memmory.

2)**File is small**. Then you have a choice, wheather to follow the first case or read file in memmory, close it and then process it.

**There is one more consideration**: while file is not closed, other processes cannot access it. That could be a problem if your logic is very long, in such case reading and closing a file first is better.